# Net-snmp can't find standard SNMPv2c mibs

Tags: snmp

I'm trying to load the snmpv2 mibs and net-snmp can't find them.

I use the -M [folder] option to tell snmpget where to find the custom mibs.

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public -M /home/myprofile/mibs 192.168.1.55 RFC1213-MIB::sysDescr
```

I get the error,

```
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): at line 0 in (none)
RFC1213-MIB::sysDescr: Unknown Object Identifier
```

What am I missing given these are standard mibs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `-M` to specify a folder, you have to make that folder contains all necessary MIB documents (not only yours, but all dependencies as well). Otherwise, Net-SNMP cannot find them (by design), which you can read Net-SNMP man page for more details,

http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpcmd.html

Thus, the easiest way is to use

`snmpget -v 2c -c public -M +/home/myprofile/mibs 192.168.1.55 RFC1213-MIB::sysDescr`